# Execute requests linearly, based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting data dynamically using jQuery AJAX requests. The Ajax calls are nested, they are called in the `success` function of each previous request. I am doing this to not put too much load on the server. The next request should only be sent if the previous one is *completed* **or** successful.

Here is the ajax code

```
function showforLanguagetra(option, catid, meta)
{
    $.ajax({       ///execute only if catid = 1,3,6,8
        type:"GET",
        url: "/Ajax1111",
        data: {
            opt: option,
            cid: catid,
            mta: meta
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#1111").html(data);

            $.ajax({           ///execute only if catid = 5,7,9
                type:"GET",
                url: "/Ajax2222",
                data: {
                    opt: option,
                    cid: catid,
                    mta: meta
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#2222").html(data);


                    $.ajax({            ///execute only if catid = 2,5,4,8
                        type:"GET",
                        url: "/Ajax3333",
                        data: {
                            opt: option,
                            cid: catid,
                            mta: meta
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#3333").html(data);


                            $.ajax({               ///execute only if catid = 6,4,8,9,0
                                type:"GET",
                                url: "/Ajax4444",
                                data: {
                                    opt: option,
                                    cid: catid,
                                    mta: meta
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                    $("#4444").html(data);


                                    $.ajax({              ///execute only if catid = 2,3,5,7,4
                                        type:"GET",
                                        url: "/Ajax5555",
                                        data: {
                                            opt: option,
                                            cid: catid,
                                            mta: meta
                                        },
                                        success: function(data){
                                            $("#5555").html(data);
                                        }
                                    });        
                                }
                            });      
                        }
                    });        
                }
            });     
        }
    }); 
}    ​
```

This code is Working Fine !

But what here required is , I want to execute ajax request based on value in **catid** as shown in comments in ajax code.
I know it lags in if condition but am new to jQuery AJAX so don't know where and how to use it

Comment: Seems to me this problem has nothing to do with jQuery or AJAX. Can't you just use if-blocks around your $.ajax calls? `if ([1,3,6,8].indexOf(catid) > -1) { $.ajax(...` and so on?

Comment: if condition is false it will stop all nested requests

Comment: Ah, you want to consider subsequent requests even if some should not be done?

Comment: Your code as it stands will not work as if `catid` is `5` then the first ajax block will not be called - and therefore the success function will not be hit and that is where you check if `cat == 5`...

Comment: @ElRonnoco  Yes you are Right !  its difficult But I think its possible by some way....

Comment: I am using nested code here because I want AJAX request in a linear way.... to prevent crashing of server  :/

Comment: Or tell me if there is any way to execute next ajax call after completion of previous one....  without using nesting

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements as your current approach will not work. Do you just want a different routine to be called for any given value of `catid`? If you just want the code to "wait" until an ajax request is done before proceeding then set `async: false` as in my example.

Comment: if async:false works then I will not use nesting and this Question will be solved automatically ...

Comment: @ElRonnoco  thanks its working and solved my problem.....  now there is no need to use nesting and I hope now i can use condition very easily  :P

Comment: Note that using `asynx: false` is a bad idea in general, since it wil block the UI. Have a look at my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Felix Oh no! I love `async: false`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps what you really want is simply the `async: false` part - this makes the ajax call complete before proceeding throught the code.

I have **updated this answer** as I don't believe you want all following calls to not fire, rather they should all fire in order and dependent on `catid`

---

To do this you will need to put `if` or `switch` blocks round your ajax calls. This will lead to even deeper nesting than you already have.

I would strongly recommened breaking this logic out into separate routines. Have one function which calls the ajax routine rather than this deep nesting.

Set `async` to `false` to make the ajax routine wait for success before continuing.

```
function callAjax( service , option catid , meta ) {
   var ret = {data:false};

    $.ajax({       
        type:"GET",
        url: service,
        async: false,
        data: {
            opt: option,
            cid: catid,
            mta: meta
        },
        success: function(data){
            ret.data = data;
        });

    return ret;
}


function showforLanguagetra(option, catid, meta) {
    var successData;

    if ( catid == 1 || catid == 3 || catid == 6 || catid == 8) {
        successData = callAjax( '\Ajax1111' , option , catid, meta ).data
        if ( successData )
            $("#1111").html(successData);
    }

    if ( catid == 5 || catid == 7 || catid == 9) {
        successData = callAjax( '\Ajax2222' , option , catid, meta ).data
        if ( successData )
            $("#2222").html(successData);
    }

    if ( catid == 2 || catid == 5 || catid == 4 || catid == 8) {
        successData = callAjax( '\Ajax3333' , option , catid, meta ).data
        if ( successData )
            $("#3333").html(successData);
    }

    // etc etc

}
```

**Note that your code doesn't really make sense** as if catid does not equal 1, 3, 6 or 8 then the later ajax calls will never be hit anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to execute functions linearly, but only if certain conditions are met?

To make things easier, you have to abstract the problem a bit. For example, figure out what all the requests have in common and where they differ. They all have a different URL, condition and success.

You can create an array of Ajax call configuration objects, iterate over them and use [`.pipe()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) to linerize them. If you return the final promise object, you will also be able to execute a function after all calls are complete.

```
var ajax_config = [{
       url: '/Ajax1111', // URL
       // a function accepting catid and returning true or false
       condition: function(catid) { 
           return catid === 1 || catid === 3 || ...;
       },
       // function to be executed when call was successful
       success: function(data) {
           $("#1111").html(data);
       }
   },
   // some for all the other calls
];

function showforLanguagetra(option, catid, meta) {
    var queue = new $.Deferred();

    // iterate over the configuration objects and add them to the
    // queue if the condition is met 
    $.each(ajax_config, function(i, config) {
        if(config.condition(catid)) {
            queue = queue.pipe(function() {
                return $.get(config.url, {
                    opt: option,
                    id: catid,
                    mta: meta
                }).done(config.success);
            });
        }
    });
    queue.resolve();
}
```